# ListFragment vs Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class, XXXFragment which extends Fragment.  XXXFragment provides a ListView.  It seems reasonable (from the class names) that I should modify XXXFragment so that it extends a ListFragment, but I can't figure out how.

Now that I know ListFragment does  extend Fragment, I think it is correct and have no idea why Android Studio is complaining.  See below for error message from Studio.  The problem is the line highlighted below.  Help greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

++++ XXXFragment  +++++

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by berman on 3/7/15.
 */
public class XXXFragment extends ListFragment {

    public XXXFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .... create & return view
            }
}
```

+++++  MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    **.add(R.id.container, new XXXFragment()) <<<**
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    }
}
```

Error message when I force Studio to compile:

```
Error:(17, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,ChatFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ChatFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

Comment: ListFragment is not a Fragment: Wrong!! Please check  android.app.Fragment
     ↳ android.app.ListFragment docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: Hmm.  You're right.  Then why does the compiler complain when I change Fragment to List Fragment.  Anyway, thanks.  I thought it was strange that they weren't.

Comment: Since you didn't posted the whole code, it is hard to Guess, but I am assuming you may be missing on few points. 1.Check if you added `cast` and 2. is your class also implements any additional interface

Comment: @JaredBurrows: Sorry, i didn't get! What should I read?

Comment: Post the whole Fragment code and the code you call from the `activity` to add the `Fragment`

Comment: @AADTechnical You already answered it.

Comment: also add what complain (error) message you are getting.

Comment: Error:(17, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,ChatFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ChatFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)

Comment: BTW, now I seem to have confused Studio.  Even when I return to Fragment (from ListFragment base class), it complains.  Any way to make AS clean up and start over with a project?

Comment: Problem seems to be related to configuration.  When the import specifies import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; things compile.  When it is android.app.Fragment it is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a conflict between import statements.
In MainActivity I have

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

In XXXFragment, I use

```
import  android.app.Fragment (or ListFragment)
```

which fails.

If I change this to

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;  (or Fragment)
```

it works.